# When is the heat semigroup Gibbs?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Defining the Laplacian on a region $Ω$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions, under what conditions on the region (or any other possible assumptions) is the semigroup it generates Gibbs, i.e. trace-class? For example, if $Ω$ has finite volume, this is the case, and the book "Heat Kernels and Spectral Theory" by E. Brian Davies (where this question is inspired from) provides one other set of conditions (involving strongly regular regions). Are there other references that study this question?

Edit: Cross-posted from math.stackexchange.com/q/4109797/87355.

Comment: cross-posted https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4109797/87355

Comment: Not sure which place is more suitable for this question @CarloBeenakker. I can delete one of the two.

Comment: it's just that posting the same question on two sites, in particularly without disclosing it, leads to duplication of efforts and should be avoided; the bounty on both sites amplifies that risk.

Comment: I understand this now, I appreciate this explanation. I'll add a link to the body of the question and know not to do this in the future.